# Как искать регулярные выражения в поисковых системах?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, поисковые-системы

Имеется регулярное выражение, например `'/^$/d'`, как осуществить поиск регулярного выражения в поисковой системе? `['/^$/d']`, `"'/^$/d'"` не работают должным образом.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под поисковой системой и зачем собственно искать регулярное выражение

Comment: В общем случае, вам следует экранировать спецсимволы. Например, так: `/\/\^\$\/d/`. https://regex101.com/r/oE8fP5/1

Comment: @Mike https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0 почему бы не иметь возможность искать регулярные выражения? Чем они хуже обычных последовательностей символов?

Comment: @Side это конечно может быть и неплохо, хотя регулярку под конкретный случай проще написать чем искать. Тем более, что в 80% случаев требуются элементарные регулярки. А поисковые системы обычно на это не рассчитаны, они просто не индексируют знаки препинания из которых в основном состоят регулярки.

Comment: @Side И все равно не понимаю, какой смысл найти где то упоминание какой то конкретной регулярки. Узнать что она делает ? Так открыв статью в вики "регулярные выражения" и просто просмотрев посимвольно написанное можно понять, даже если до этого никогда с ними не сталкивался. И еще не надо забывать, что существует с десяток несовместимых диалектов регулярок. Например модификтор /d, в вашем примере, очень редкая вещь, есть в диалекте perl v 5.14 для старого режима работы с unicode. более нигде его не видел

Comment: @Mike если рассуждать таким образом, то можно прийти к выводу что ненужно искать упоминание, надо писать все самому. Предположим так получилось, что я запомнил именно это регулярное выражение, мне нужно найти его упоминание в сети, я помню, что я выполнял его для удаления пустых строк в файле. Найдя упоминание данного регулярного выражения я бы понял что речь идет о небольшом языке программирования, а также утилите sed. Я не считаю что такой поиск бессмыслен.

Comment: Правда ваша регулярка содержит /d который sed не понимает и в диалекте sed обычно приходиться перед ^ и $ ставить обратную косую. И что за небольшой язык программирования ? кроме того регулярки же используются в десятках языков, так что вы найдете  упоминания всех языков в контексте определения пустых строк

Comment: @Mike Прочитайте про sed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#Other_sed_commands более того язык sed является полным по Тьюрингу. Данное выражение непременно укажет на sed, что мне и необходимо.

Comment: @Side Я знаю что такое sed, просто редко им пользуюсь и неверно истолковал вашу строку, потому как воспринял ее как настоящее "регулярное выражение" (вы сами ее так назвали), потому как в регулярных выражениях нет ни удалений ни замен. Т.е. то что у вас между косыми - это регулярка, а буква "d" - это исключительно _действие_ и исключительно sed. В большинстве языков поддерживающих регулярки после косой идут модификаторы

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: Ответ готов.​​​​

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы действительно считаете что регулярные выражения, их использование и поиск не относятся к программированию?

Comment: @Side, я считаю, что синтаксис поисковых запросов не относится к программированию. кроме случая, когда речь идёт о разработке и реализации такого синтаксиса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, искать регулярное выражение - это что-то странное. Скорее всего, следует поискать что-то другое. Например, написать текстом назначение этого выражения.

Но если очень хочется, то можно использовать поисковую систему, воспринимающую вводимый текст как есть. [Утверждается](//webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters) что есть только одна такая поисковая система - [SymbolHound](//symbolhound.com/).

> SymbolHound is a search engine that doesn't ignore special characters. This means you can easily search for symbols like &, %, and ^, or even less common characters such as ©, ¬, and µ.

Лично у меня ни разу не возникало желания в ней что-то поискать, но соответствующие ссылки упоминаются в одном из ответов на [Why is asking for operators functionality high-quality content within JavaScript community?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313593/4928642)

Comment: Контрабанда ответов ))